# Using RegEx to extract number from alphanumeric string

Tags: regex

I need to identify substring 'X.123' and/or 'X.8' in a longer string of alphanumeric data.  Ex:

```
A cow flew over the moon in the X.123 module, not the X.124.3 module, 
and certainly not the X.125C78 module.  The cow poo-pooed the X.8 module.
```

How would I exclude the second and third instance?  This is what I've come up with so far to get the "X.123" part:

```
/[X][\.][0-9]{1,4}/
```

I'm not exactly sure how to make the expression stop at any non-numeric character (ex: X124C78)

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **\b** is nice in this context, i would use it like this:

```
/\bX\.\d{1,4}\b/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
/X\.[0-9]{1,4}(?=\s|$)/
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use this. The `\b` in the start helps avoiding matches such as `AX.123`

```
/\bX\.\d+(?=\s|$)/

preg_match_all('/\bX\.\d+(?=\s|$)/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```